# How can I download the Mavericks installer to a Windows PC?

Tags: macos, mac, usb-flash-drive, installer, osx-mavericks

I don't want to *install* Mavericks onto a Windows PC - I want to to download the installer (5Gb) onto a Windows PC and then install it on a Mac from a USB drive.

For reasons I won't go into, it's not practical to download the installer directly to the Macbook, but I can download it at another location where we only have Windows PCs
 (and a more generous data allocation).  I want to then copy it to a USB drive and install it on the Mac.  Possible?

Comment: Its possible.  There exists torrents that provide you the require .iso file.  You won't find very many solutions outside of a torrent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your only possibility is either to find a direct download or a torrent of this iso, since Apple only allows to download it from the Mac App Store.

Comment: I found numerous torrents, but too many of them were acccompanied by complaints of dud ISOs, which made me a little nervous.  I don't know why Apple don't just make the ISO's available.